# Реализация игры в крестики-нолики по сети

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте.

Уже несколько месяцев изучаю программирование под андроид. Решил написать простую игру - крестики-нолики через Интернет. Клиенты на андроид подключаются к серверу на хостинге каком-нибудь.  Вся сложность в том, что я не понимаю, как реализовать саму логику на сервере. Например, игрок #1 сделал ход. А как сообщить второму игроку о ходе  первого? Нужно подключатся через сокеты к серверу или делать лонгпуллы?

Прошу подсказать сам алгоритм или ссылки на нужный мне материал. Спасибо большое за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

А если передавать состояние игрока по сокету.

Допустим игрок#1 :
1) Сделал ход - отправил данные на сервер
2) Ожидание хода противника
3) Получения информации о ходе противника (отрисовать у себя на экране)

Ожидание можно сделать в отдельном потоке, чтобы все не висло.

А на сервере можно так: 
1) Принять информацию о ходе 1 игрока.
2) Послать игроку 2 сообщение о том, что игрок 1 сходил.
3) Принять информацию о ходе 2 игрока
4) Послать игроку 1 сообщение о том, что игрок 2 сходил.

P.S не знаю особенностей андройда, но на java с сокетами это бы работало.

Comment: Тоесть на сервере тоже java должна быть? Или без разницы?

Comment: @raplider, без разницы. Хоть бэйсик (лишь бы умел с сокетами работать).